# How to get the public key from sshd server without touching the known_hosts file?

Tags: sshd

Are there any tricks to get the public key (the line that goes into the known_hosts file after I answered yes after connecting with ssh) of a server?

Comment: I just want to check that behind a domain is the IP that is really behind the domain. (I can check this by comparing the public ssh key of the domain+IP - so I need to connect twice with ssh client: once using the domain as destination, and once using the IP as destination that I got from the dig command)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `ssh-keyscan domain-name` and it'll output the public key for you.